# OpenMP many for loops issue

Tags: openmp

I want to parallel the outer for loop, but I tried instructions below, and it turned out to be wrong. I hope you can help with this.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,ii,j) reduction(+:Number1)
    for(ii=1;ii<numbers_of_sieve;ii++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<area;j++)
            flags[j]=1;

        int a=sqrt((double)(1+ii))*1024;
        for(int k=0;k<Number;k++)
        {
            if(sieve[k]<=a)
            {
                __int64 x=(sieve[k]+(-(ii*area))%sieve[k])%sieve[k];

                for(__int64 m=ii*area+x;m<(1+ii)*area;m+=sieve[k])
                    flags[m-ii*area]=0;
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<(1<<20);i++)
        {
            if(flags[i]==1)
            {
                //fprintf(fp,"%I64d\t",i+ii*area);
                Number1++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Define "wrong" please.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what does mean your "and it turned out to be wrong." But flags (array?) must be declared as private or it must be declared inside loop.

P.S.

Please check that your program works right in serial mode before trying to run in parallel mode. Compare, for example, two line:

```
   for(j=0;j<area;j++)
```

and

```
    for(i=0;i<(1<<20);i++)
```

Think about - what will be if `area != (1<<20)` or `size of flags != area`.

Comment: @user2958667 declare array flags as private in **pragma omp parallel for**